# How to test in-app-purchase on iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

The IOS Simulator doesn't support Storekit which allows you to perform in app-payment. To test it, you can create a test user through iTunes connect, this user can't be your usual Apple email, it needs to be a new one. I would like to try in-app purchase on my iPhone using that test user, but I don't want to wipe it out completely by switching user. I don't own any second device. Is there a way to specify a user ID (email) when performing a purchase in my application?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to perform an in-app purchase on your own iPhone you will be prompted to enter your password for the current account. What you need to do is to log out of the App Store, then you will be prompt to enter your email+password when trying to purchase. To log out from App Store, go to Settings > iTunes & App Store, click on the Apple Id and "log out".